# How to cascade a custom config in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, config

I have the following code, which behaves exactly as expected:

```
View::addNamespace('template', [
    storage_path().'/contexts/'.$context.'/views',     // live edits
    base_path().'/resources/views/context/'.$context, //template base
    base_path().'/resources/views',             // generic fallback
    base_path().'/app/views/template1',          // legacy fallback
]);
```

I've done literally the same thing with Lang and Config, but they do not work at all. My small research indicates that Config::addNamespace and Lang::addNamespace do not accept an array as the hints parameter.

So basically, I have this file:
"app/lang/en/{$context}/home.php"

```
<?php return array(
    'animal' => 'large cat',
);
```

where Lang::get('home.animal') normally returns 'small dog', I would expect to conditionally say "large cat" instead if the following code is ran:

```
Lang::addNamespace('default', [
    base_path().'app/lang/en/{$context}/',
    base_path().'app/lang/en/',
]);
```

Does Laravel or any Laravel package support a method to do this, with or without namespaces?